# Ito's formula for Jump process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson

Let $\{N_t\,|\,0\leq t\leq T\}$ be a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda>0$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_t,P)$ with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ and 
\begin{align}
X_t=e^{(\lambda-\eta)\,t}\,\left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda}\right)^{N_t},
\end{align}
where $\eta>0$.How can I obtain $dX_t$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Ito's lemma,

\begin{align}
dX_t=\frac{\partial X_t}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial X_t}{\partial N(t)}dN_t+\frac{1}{2!}\frac{\partial^2 X_t}{\partial N^2_t}(dN_t)^2+\frac{\partial^2 X_t}{\partial N_t\partial t}{}dN_tdt+\frac{1}{3!}\frac{\partial^3 X_t}{\partial N^3_t}(dN_t)^3+...
\end{align}
Since $dN_t\,dt = 0, (dN_t)^2 = (dN_t)^3 = . . . = dN_t$, we have
\begin{align}
dX_t=\frac{\partial X_t}{\partial t}dt+\left(\frac{\partial X_t}{\partial N_t}+\frac{1}{2!}\frac{\partial^2 X_t}{\partial N^2_t}+\frac{1}{3!}\frac{\partial^3 X_t}{\partial N^3_t}+...\right)dN_t.
\end{align}
On the other hand
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial X_t}{\partial t}=(\lambda-\eta)\,X_t\\
&\frac{\partial^n X_t}{\partial N_t^n}=\left[\ln \left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda}\right)\right]^nX_t,\\
\end{align} 
therefore

\begin{align}
dX_t=(\lambda-\eta)\,X_tdt+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left[\ln \left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda}\right)\right]^nX_t\,dN_t
\end{align}
We know $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left[\ln \left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda}\right)\right]^n=exp\left(\ln \left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda}\right)\right)-1=\frac{\eta}{\lambda}-1=\frac{\eta-\lambda}{\lambda}$ thus we have
\begin{align}
dX_t=(\lambda-\eta)\,X_tdt+\frac{\eta-\lambda}{\lambda}X_t\,dN_t
\end{align}

Comment: Why do the higher derivatives with respect to N matter? I just dont see it atm.

Comment: Ito's Lemma isn't really necessary, since Poisson processes have finite variation.

Comment: @Phun $\frac{\partial^n X_t}{\partial N_t^n}=\left[\ln \left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda}\right)\right]^nX_t $ for $n=1,2,3,...$

Comment: @ quasi  Yes ,Poisson processes have finite variation, But if we don't use Ito lemma then we can not obtain $dX_t$

Comment: @Behrouz I think you can use the product rule of ordinary calculus.  The jump term itself doesn't require calculus at all.

Comment: @quasi What is your solution?

Comment: @quasi Please Add your solution.

Comment: @Behrouz thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

Write $X_t = A_t B_t$ with $A_t = e^{(\lambda - \eta)t}$ and $B_t = \left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda} \right)^{N_t}$.

Then $dX_t = A_t dB_t + B_t dA_t$ by the product rule of calculus.  There are no second order terms since both $A_t$ and $B_t$ are finite variation (i.e. $\langle A_t, B_t\rangle$= 0).

Next, $dA_t = (\lambda - \eta)A_t dt$, and $dB_t = B_t \cdot \left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda} - 1\right)dN_t$.  The form of $dA_t$ follows from normal calculus, and the form of $dB_t$ follows from subtracting before and after values of the jump process.

Using the two paragraphs above, we get $$dX_t = A_tB_t \left( \left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda} - 1 \right)dN_t + (\lambda - \eta)dt\right) = X_t\left( \left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda} - 1 \right)dN_t + (\lambda - \eta)dt\right).$$

Edit for @Behrouz:

$dB_t = \left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda}\right)^{N_t} - \left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda}\right)^{N_{t-}}$.

When $N_t$ does not jump, this value is zero.  When $N_t$ does jump, it is equal to

$\left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda}\right)^{N_t} - \left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda}\right)^{N_{t} - 1}
= B_{t-}\left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda} - 1 \right)dN_t$

So actually in my original answer, I should have minuses for left hand limits to be technically correct.

Comment: Why $dB_t = B_t \cdot \left(\frac{\eta}{\lambda} - 1\right)dN_t$?Do you use Ito's lemma?

Comment: No, it's just arithmetic...The poisson jumps by 1, so $B_t$ jumps correspondingly.

Comment: please prove it

Comment: Let $f : n \mapsto  a^n$ then $f(N_t) = f(0) + \sum_{s\leq t, \Delta N_s \neq 0} f(N_s) - f(N_{s-}) = f(0) + \sum_{s\leq t, \Delta N_s \neq 0} (a-1) f(N_{s_-})\Delta N_s$ which can be rewritten $f(N_t) = f(0) + \int_0^t (a-1)f(N_{s-})dN_s.$

Comment: @AFK , I accepted,but , do these answers are different?

Comment: @quasi Thank u,your solution was perfect by Hippocrates our discussion!

Comment: @quasi Thanks,but title of my question is, Ito's formula for Jump process.